# Pnotify change text after open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, pnotify

I want to use pnotify like status bar. I'm saving some records to database and i want to show that in pnotify like this.

"Saving 28 / 209"

But i didn't see any example to change pnotify content after it's open.

Here my javascript. This works but open a lots of notify.

```
var sayac = 0;
var i = setInterval(function () {
    var veriler = { 
        NotPuan: nesneler[sayac].value, 
        OgrenciID: nesneler[sayac].alt, 
        PayID: nesneler[sayac].name 
    };
    var listele = $.post("NotGiris/NotKaydet", veriler);

    $.pnotify({ 
        title: 'DURUM', 
        text: 'Kaydediliyor' + sayac + ' / ' + nesneler.length, 
        type: 'success', 
        delay: 1000 
    });

    console.log(Date());
    sayac++;
    if (sayac === nesneler.length) {
        clearInterval(i);
        window.location.replace('/Ders/Detay?Uyari=1');
    }
}, 200);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the **update** function on the pnotify instance.

```
var notice = new PNotify({
  title: 'Regular Notice',
  text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.'
});
$("#update").on('click', function() {
  notice.update({
    title: 'Updated title!'
  })
});
```

... i.e., simply save the instance you are creating and then call `.update(options)` on it.

See it in action on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XmkEXAZCoM3C93FmqoU4?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tadeas. I solved.

```
var notice = new $.pnotify({
        title: 'UYARI',
        text: '',
        type: 'success',
        delay: 200000
    });
    $(".ui-pnotify-history-container").remove();

    var sayac = 0;
    var i = setInterval(function () {

        var veriler = { NotPuan: nesneler[sayac].value, OgrenciID: nesneler[sayac].alt, PayID: nesneler[sayac].name };
        var listele = $.post("NotGiris/NotKaydet", veriler);
        //$.pnotify({ title: 'DURUM', text: 'Kaydediliyor' + sayac + ' / ' + nesneler.length, type: 'success', delay: 200 });
        notice.pnotify({
            title: 'UYARI',
            text: 'Kaydediliyor: ' + sayac + ' / ' + nesneler.length, delay: 200000,
            type: 'success',
            delay: 200000
        })
        //$.pnotify.pnotify({text: 'Kaydediliyor' + sayac + ' / ' + nesneler.length, delay: 200000})
        console.log(Date());
        sayac++;
        if (sayac === nesneler.length) {
            clearInterval(i);
            window.location.replace('/Ders/Detay?Uyari=1');
        }
    }, 200);
```